# Can't resolve 'fs' in firebase-admin/lib' when using nextjs monorepo project with lerna

Tags: reactjs, next.js, firebase-admin, monorepo, lerna

I have a Lerna MonoRepo project setup.

Like

```
root/
   lerna.json
   packgae.json
   package.lock.json
   packages/
       app1 - Create react app (with firebase sdk dependency)
       app2 - Next Js app (with firebase-admin dependency)
       components - shared react components.
```

when I try to build next js app then following error occurs.

> Blockquote
> ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'root-project/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib'.

Comment: Make sure you only use `firebase-admin` in server-only code (e.g. `getStaticProps`, `getServerSideProps`, API routes).

Answer (score 8):

[firebase-admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin) package is supposed to run in Node environments, not in browser projects. 'fs' is a built-in Nodejs package.

Comment: How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Extending on vijayst's answer: You need to use the examples given for 'Web version 9' on de firebase docs. You cannot use `firebase-admin` on web. You can only use it server-side. You need to use the `firebase` package